# Return to a menu choice in A++

Tags: c++, loops, menu

This is a hard question, and i've seen answers to this question, but those answers are not in dumb enough terms for a noob like me. So, my question is, that if I were to go into a menu, choose an option, complete that option, and I need to go back to the main menu to do another option, can anyone explain in Noobie terms? Thanks.

An Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Main Menu:" << endl;
    cout << "01. This Option" << endl;
    cout << "02. Another Option" << endl;
    int option;
    cin >> option;

    if(option==1)
    {
        //do stuff and then go back somehow
    }
    if(option==2)
    {
        //do other stuff and come back somehow
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "INVALID!" << endl;
        system("Pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just introduce a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> //this is needed to use the function system
//#include <windows.h> //not used here
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(;;) //infinite loop
    {
        cout << "Main Menu:" << endl;
        cout << "01. This Option" << endl;
        cout << "02. Another Option" << endl;
        int option;
        cin >> option;

        if(option==1)
        {
            //do stuff and then go back somehow
        }
        else if(option==2) // else should be here, or the program will end when option==1
        {
            //do other stuff and come back somehow
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "INVALID!" << endl;
            system("Pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I implemented it into an example program and I'm using this program as a reference for the program I'm working on now, this program is still in the 'white board' stage but how do I exit the loop without exiting the program? Lets say I have a database program, I enter a name and create an account, now I need to get back to the main menu without the main menu being in the loop, I have a for loop inside a for loop and I need to break out of a loop without returning 0, any help?

Comment: Use `brerak;` instead of `return 0;`.